# Is there a dns-prefetching equivalent for SSL handshakes?

Tags: html, ssl, web, prefetch

We load data from a few subdomains/3rd parties. This causes about 100ms of SSL handshaking for each domain. I'm wondering if there is a way to "pre-fetch-handshake" similar to how dns-prefetching works. Does dns-prefetching already do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there is a pre-fetch-handshake and I doubt that it would make sense. DNS prefetching is done for links in the page so that the browser already knows the IP address of the target host when the user decides to click the link. This might be immediately after loading the page, some minutes later, hours later or never. DNS prefetching also does not tie any resources on the server. It just warms up the local DNS cache by asking the upstream DNS resolver which might either have the record already or will resolve the query and thus have the entry in the cache, available for other clients too.

Contrary to this a pre-fetch-handshake for HTTPS would need to create a TCP connection directly to the target server, do the SSL handshake and then wait for the client to click. This ties up resources at the client and the server so after some time of inactivity the server will close the connection to free these resources. Thus in many cases this would just waste resources on both sides since the link will never be clicked or will only be clicked after the server already closed the idle connection.

The situation is a bit different if the link points to a site with an already existing connection, like a same-site link when loading a page from some site. Today browsers use persistent HTTP connections and will try to leave the connection to a site open for a while in case more requests need to be send. If the user then clicks the same-site link an existing connection might be used which was still open from previous requests. Of course these connections tie up resources on the server too so the server will close the connection after some idle time too.